# Create Mail and mark as send without Sending it

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I want to migrate my email from my old email environment (non-Microsoft) to Office 365.

To do this, I want to use the REST API. I can already create messages but they are always marked as "draft". Is there any way to create message and mark them as sent with the old sent date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration scenarios are not a good fit for the REST API. You should instead use the tools that come with Office 365 to handle email migration.

For a general overview, see [Ways to migrate multiple email accounts to Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-migrate-multiple-email-accounts-to-Office-365-0a4913fe-60fb-498f-9155-a86516418842). Based on the limited information you provided, you'll most likely want to look at [Migrate email from another IMAP-enabled email system](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-you-need-to-know-about-migrating-your-IMAP-mailboxes-to-Office-365-3fe19996-29bc-4879-aab9-5a622b2f1481?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and [Migrate email and contacts to Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Migrate-email-and-contacts-to-Office-365-a3e3bddb-582e-4133-8670-e61b9f58627e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).